# I am using .so files generated by different versions of ndk-build, will this cause any potential issue?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an android app with sdk 28 in android studio 3.3 .

Currently I have two .so files.

The first one was build with **ndk-r10e**, and in its `Application.mk`, I find **`APP_STL := gnustl_static`** .

And the second one was build with **ndk-r16b**, with **`APP_STL := c++_static`**.

**Will this lead to any potential issue?**

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#one_stl_per_app

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your information. I will take this into consideration in future projects, although this time ndk-r12b magically works for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said, read developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#one_stl_per_app. What you've done is definitely not compatible. Even if you switch to c++_static for your first library, the libc++ ABI has changed since r10.

We maintain compatibility across NDKs whenever we can, but some bugs require non-compatible changes to fix. It's also not something we actively test. Strictly speaking, you should use the same version of the NDK to build everything in your application. That's not always possible, but you should do so whenever it is.

Comment: I finally find ndk-r12b magically works for both, thanks anyway.